# cannot find symbol in alchemy api error

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I'm getting an error when trying to use the AlchemyLanguage API in Java

#### pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### java class

```
@WebServlet("/SimpleServlet2")
public class API extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    AlchemyLanguage service = new AlchemyLanguage();
    service.setApiKey("API_KEY_HERE");

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TEXT, "IBM Watson won the Jeopardy television show hosted by Alex Trebek");

    DocumentSentiment sentiment = service.getSentiment(params);
    System.out.println(sentiment);
    response.getWriter().print(sentiment.toString());
  }
}
```

#### Error log

```
[ERROR] src/main/java/wasdev/sample/‌​servlet/API.java:[17,39]
 cannot find symbol symbol: class AlchemyLanguage location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API
[ERROR] src/main/java/wasdev/sample/‌​servlet/API.java:[22,19]
 cannot find symbol symbol: variable FileUtils location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API
[ERROR] src/main/java/wasdev/sample/‌​servlet/API.java:[25,9]
 cannot find symbol symbol: variable CredentialUtils location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API
[ERROR] src/main/java/wasdev/sample/‌​servlet/API.java:[27,22]
 cannot find symbol symbol: variable CredentialUtils
```

Comment: [ERROR] /home/pipeline/0e04c628-e041-41a9-bc51-0e99f59817aa/src/main/java/wasdev/sample/servlet/API.java:[17,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AlchemyLanguage
  location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API

Comment: [ERROR] /home/pipeline/0e04c628-e041-41a9-bc51-0e99f59817aa/src/main/java/wasdev/sample/servlet/API.java:[17,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AlchemyLanguage
  location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API

Comment: [ERROR] /home/pipeline/0e04c628-e041-41a9-bc51-0e99f59817aa/src/main/java/wasdev/sample/servlet/API.java:[22,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FileUtils
  location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API
[ERROR] /home/pipeline/0e04c628-e041-41a9-bc51-0e99f59817aa/src/main/java/wasdev/sample/servlet/API.java:[25,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable CredentialUtils
  location: class wasdev.sample.servlet.API [ERROR] /home/pipeline/0e04c628-e041-41a9-bc51-0e99f59817aa/src/main/java/wasdev/sample/servlet/API.java:[27,22] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable CredentialUtils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the code in your question. Seems like your problem is related to the classpath. Take a look at this sample application which includes the java-sdk and exposes a JAX-RS class with some endpoints.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/retrieve-and-rank-java

Make sure you pom is pulling all the dependencies as it seems like the java-sdk is not in the classpath even that it's in the `pom.xml`